# update existing column values and insert new in record doesn't exist in SQL when importing from CSV

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssis, etl

Can you PLEASE help me on following?

We have payroll software that runs on SQL Server. I have to update certain payroll category from the SQL Server so that it can reflect on the software.

This is my Excel file:

```
Employee Number  Payroll Category  Rate
------------------------------------------
111111           011               32.21
111111           012               56.23
111111           013               12.52
111111           021               45.21
111112           011               36.21
111112           012               56.23
111112           013               42.54
111112           021               85.21
```

These are the current values in my database table `Masterpaycard`

```
 Employee Number     Payroll Category  Rate
 -------------------------------------------
    111111           011               0.00
    111111           012               0.00
    111111           013               10.25

    111112           011               36.21
    111112           012               12.50
    111112           013               41.25
    111112           021               85.21
```

So if you see following record is not present in the database, but present in the `.CSV`, then I have to insert it.

```
 111111           021               45.21
```

Here Employee Number and Payroll Category are FKs from the `Employee` and `Payroll Category` tables.

So my final results should look like in the database and in the front end something like this.

```
Employee Number    Payroll Category    Rate
--------------------------------------------
    111111           011               32.21
    111111           012               56.23
    111111           013               12.52
    111111           021               45.21
    111112           011               36.21
    111112           012               56.23
    111112           013               42.54
    111112           021               85.21
```

I guess in simple words if payroll category match in `MASTERPAYCARD` table then just update the category with value from `.CSV`, and if we can not find Payrollcategory than insert that as new category for that employee and add value too from CSV.

Please help.

Comment: I would recommend loading the entire Excel CSV as is into a holding table. Then you can do some queries to determine exactly what needs to be inserted or updated.

Comment: Since I am kind of new to SQL can you please show me an example?

Comment: Look up update with a join.  SO is not a coding service.

Comment: Google `SSIS UPSERT` and you will find examples.

Comment: I was able to partialiy do this via SSIS->lookup->match output->update query.

Comment: Thank you Paparazzi, for boosting me up. I took your comment as inspiration and solved the problem. I will be posting it very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of approach you need to take...

```
create table #Table1 (
    id int,
    value varchar(10)
)

create table #Table2 (
    id int,
    value varchar(10)
)

insert into #Table1 values (1, 'AAA')
insert into #Table1 values (2, 'BBB')

insert into #Table2 values (1, 'ZZZ')
insert into #Table2 values (3, 'CCC')

select * from #Table1
select * from #Table2

--insert data from Table2 into Table1 if it doesn't already exist in Table1
insert into #Table1 
select #Table2.* from #Table2
left join #Table1 on #Table2.id = #Table1.id
where #Table1.id is null

--update data in Table1 from Table2 if it does already exist in Table1
update #Table1 set value = #Table2.value
from #Table2
left join #Table1 on #Table2.id = #Table1.id
where #Table1.id is not null

select * from #Table1
```

Comment: Thanks. This is also nice solution.